# How can I find $x(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given this equation:

$$\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^2} + a \frac{dx}{dt} + x =0$$

and given that:  $x(0)=0$, $\frac{dx}{dt}(0)=1 $.

($a$ is parameter and given that $a<2$)

How can I find what is $x(t)$ ? I will be happy for help (or event hints).

Comment: Try to substitute $x=\exp(\lambda t)$.

Comment: after the hint above we get $$x(t)=c_1 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{a^2-4}-a\right) t}+c_2
   e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-4}-a\right) t}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to solve
$$
f''+af+f=0
$$
If you search for exponential function solution, you'll have to solve
$$
r^2+ar+1=0 
$$
Then $\Delta=a^2-4<0$ because $a<2$.
The two solutions are
$$
r=\frac{-a \pm i\sqrt{a-2}\sqrt{a+2}}{2}
$$
Then the solutions are

> $$
> f\left(t\right)=e^{-\frac{a}{2}t}\left(\lambda_1\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}t\right)+\lambda_2 \sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2-4}}{2}t\right)\right)
> $$

I let you find the two constants $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with initial conditions to find $x$ for all $t$.

Comment: thank you. can you give me sources for read about it?

Comment: http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/f11/m1312/second_order.pdf , hope you like it ^^

Comment: Thank you, by the way, have you source for non-homogeneous too?